# for loop over the first column of a matrix and mean

Tags: matlab

I have codes to solve some stochastic equations.
My function file

```
[S,T]=simByEuler(MDL, nPeriods,'DeltaTime',params.dt);
```

is running fine where S is a matrix its first column is theta and the second column is phi. S has 1001 rows. T is a vector of time of dimension 1001*1. Please ignore T. Focus on S which has 2 columns theta and phi,
 i.e S=[theta,  phi]. Dimension of S is 1001*2.

I want to write a for loop to generate 500 sample of the theta then take the mean of all of these 500. To start, the code I put in the question has random parameters. This code should be inside the for loop so that as the loop start again the code:

```
[S,T]=simByEuler(MDL, nPeriods,'DeltaTime',params.dt);
```

will generate random variable and run the for loop till end to generate new theta. What I am looking for is to have a block of these 500 theta (remember theta is a column). This block should be of size 1001*500. Then I want to take the mean of all columns in this block so the mean should be of size 1001*1.

My questions are:

1) How to write a for loop to generate this block of size 1001*500.

2) How to take the mean of all columns in the block so that the mean will be of size 1001*1.

I hope my questions are clear and I really appreciate any help.

Comment: `mean(T(1:500,1)`?

Comment: little correction here @StewieGriffin ;)

Comment: Do you mean I do not need to use for loop?

Comment: But size(mean(T(1:500),1))=1*500, which is not correct. The mean should be of size or dimension 1001*1.

Comment: First off, your code isn't the same as the one I wrote,,, Do you want `mean(T, 2)`? It doesn't match the question text, but it's the only mean I can think of that will have dimension 1000x1.

Comment: No. I do not ask about the mean of T. I edit the post to clarify question.

Comment: _"This block should be of size 1001*500"_. If you have 500 columns, and _"take the mean of all columns"_ than you get a (row) vector with **500** values, not 1001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

```
N = 500; % the size of a block
S = zeros(1001,2,N);
for k = 1:N
    [S(:,:,k),T]=simByEuler(MDL, nPeriods,'DeltaTime',params.dt);
end
mean_theta = mean(squeeze(S(:,1,:)),2);
```

Comment: it gives error: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: S in your code has size 1001*2*500.  If I say: theta_s=S(:,1); to extract the first column of S, then how can use for loop to compute theta_s(2), theta_s(3),...theta_s(500). Then Take theses theta_s(1)...theta_s(500) to form a block where every column in the block is theta_s(i). Then compute the mean of the columns of this block. I hope its clear. @EBH

Comment: @David (1) You write that `S` is a matrix size 1001*2, and that's exactly what `S(:,:,k)` is, so that shouldn't be a problem. (2) The function `squeeze(S(:,1,:))` take all the first columns from the `N` repetitions, and concat them to one matrix in size 1001*500. Try to just run `S = rand(1001,2,N)` instead of the loop, and see how `mean_theta` takes the mean of the right values.

Comment: Thank you so much. The code works fine. Only one question if I want to plot these 500 thetas against T, how to do this should it be inside the loop. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you try just `plot(mean_theta,T)`? (after the loop...)

Comment: Yes I did, but I would like to plot these 500 thetas. I plot mean_theta and works fine.

Comment: You want to create 500 figures? or have 500 series of data in one figure? Either way seems to me very unclear way to present your data.

Comment: @ EBH Got it. In the code you present, before end the loop I plot the 500 thetas using: plot(T,S(:,2,k)); So this will generate 500 thetas and then compute the mean and plot it as discussed. Thank you for your valuable time and effort.

Comment: I think you plot phi instead of theta, i.e. the second column of S instead of the first.